# Does atexit wait for other threads to die?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, atexit

Are the functions registered with atexit() the last functions to be executed? Is it possible that other threads at this time are still running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are the functions registered with atexit() the last functions to be
>   executed?

The atexit() calls will be executed in the main thread after the main thread finishes executing.  Other than that, no guarantees are made.

> Is it possible that other threads at this time are still running?

Yes, if you haven't taken steps to stop the other threads and join() them before main() returns.  In general you want to do an explicit, controlled shutdown of all of your threads, as the C (or C++) runtime will not do it for you, and letting them continue to run even as the main() thread is exiting introduces the possibility that they will try to access resources that main() has deallocated as part of its shutdown sequence, which will invoke undefined behavior (often experienced as an occasional, not-easily-reproducible crash during program shutdown)

Comment: I guess this is not true. atexit() is called when exit() is called. You can have your main-thread call pthread_exit and the other threads will continue to execute until one of them calls exit().

Comment: Who said they were “C++ threads”? `atexit()` could be the C version, but I don’t know if there are differences in the specifications — let alone the implementations!

Comment: @PJTraill You're right, I will change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @今天春天 I've modified my answer so it now covers the main-thread-calling-exit() case also, thank you.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you very much for your reply. Is it specified in any standard or implementation defined?

Comment: atexit() is specified in the ISO C standard, but until recently, threads were not, and therefore any thread-related behavior was implementation defined or undefined.  Threads are specified in the C11/C++11 standards, but I don't know what (if anything) those standards say about thread interactions with atexit().